# Trouble find value in list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops

I have two lists. The first is `a_list` and is like this:

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
```

The second is `b_list`, and it's a list with lists in it. It's like this:

```
b_list = [['a',1,'b'],['c',2,'g'],['e',3,'5']
```

What I'm trying to do is use `a_list` to find the correct `b_list` and print the `value[2]` in the `b_list`.

My code looks like:

```
for a in a_list:
    for b in b_list:
        if b[1] == a:
            print b[2]
```

The actually `a_list` has 136 values in it. And the real `b_list` has 315 lists in it.

I had initially written code to index the b item and remove it from `b_list` if `b[1] == a`.

I've taken that code out in order to solve the real problem.

Comment: And what is the real problem? You don't state what goes wrong.

Comment: "I had initially written code to index the `b` item and remove it from `b_list` if `b[1] == a`." Once you get past this problem and try to restore that code, you're just going to have another problem. You cannot remove elements from a `list` while iterating over it. But if you look at the Related questions on the right, you'll find the solution very quickly. The tl;dr is: `b_list = [b for b in b_list if b[1] in a_list]`, or an equivalent call to `filter`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to loop over `a_list`; a simple `in` test would suffice:

```
for b in b_list:
    if b[1] in a_list:
        print b[2]
```

This would perform better if you made `a_list` a set:

```
a_set = set(a_list)

for b in b_list:
    if b[1] in a_set:
        print b[2]
```

Either way, this code prints:

```
b
g
5
```

for your example data.

Comment: Will this work if the value in a_list has multiple lists in b_list?

Comment: @TDNS: No reason that won't work. Each sublist in `b_list` is tested separately against `a_set` or `a_list`, which is not altered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,5]

b_list = [['a',1,'b'],['c',2,'g'],['e',3,'5'],
          ['d',4,'h'],['Z',5,'X'],['m',6,'i']]

print 'a_list ==',a_list
print '\nb_list before :\n',b_list

print '\nEnumerating b_list in reversed order :'
L = len(b_list)
print ('  i       el          L-i  b_list[L-i]  \n'
       '  -------------------------------------')
for i,el in enumerate(b_list[::-1],1):
    print '  %d  %r     %d  %r' % (i,el,L-i,b_list[L-i])


L = len(b_list)
for i,el in enumerate(b_list[::-1],1):
    if el[1] in a_list:
        del b_list[L-i]


print  '\nb_list after :\n',b_list
```

result

```
a_list == [1, 2, 3, 5]

b_list before :
[['a', 1, 'b'], ['c', 2, 'g'], ['e', 3, '5'],
 ['d', 4, 'h'], ['Z', 5, 'X'], ['m', 6, 'i']]

Enumerating b_list in reversed order :
  i       el          L-i  b_list[L-i]  
  -------------------------------------
  1  ['m', 6, 'i']     5  ['m', 6, 'i']
  2  ['Z', 5, 'X']     4  ['Z', 5, 'X']
  3  ['d', 4, 'h']     3  ['d', 4, 'h']
  4  ['e', 3, '5']     2  ['e', 3, '5']
  5  ['c', 2, 'g']     1  ['c', 2, 'g']
  6  ['a', 1, 'b']     0  ['a', 1, 'b']

b_list after :
[['d', 4, 'h'], ['m', 6, 'i']]
```

The reason why **it is necessary to iterate in b_list in reversed order** is the one said by *abarnert* and explained hereafter by the doc:

> Note: There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
>   loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An
>   internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and
>   this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached
>   the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop. This can lead to nasty
>   bugs that can be avoided by making a temporary copy using a slice of
>   the whole sequence, e.g.,
>
> for x in a[:]:
>       if x < 0: a.remove(x)
>
> http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement